# Find equation of plane given plane point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry, solid-geometry

So I am given one plane point $M(5,2,0)$, also two points which are not plane points: $P(6,1,-1)$ distance to plane $1$, also point $Q(0,5,4)$ distance to plane $3$. How find equation of plane with the information given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

Suppose that an equation of the plane $\mathscr P$ to be find is $\mathscr P \equiv ax+by+cz+d=0$ where $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. By hypothesis, $M$ belongs to the plane. Hence $5a+2b+d=0$.

Also the distance of a point of coordinates $(x,y,z)$ to $\mathscr P$ is $\vert ax+by+cz+d \vert$. Therefore we also have $$\begin{cases}
\vert 6a+b-c+d \vert = 1\\
\vert 5b +4c+d \vert =3
\end{cases}$$ Replacing with $d=-5a-2b$ we get
$$\begin{cases}
\vert a-b-c\vert = 1\\
\vert 5a-3b -4c\vert =3
\end{cases}$$ So you have to solve the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
a^2+b^2+c^2=1\\
\vert a-b-c\vert = 1\\
\vert 5a-3b -4c\vert =3
\end{cases}$$